# NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR constant

Tags: php, coding-style, namespaces

Having namespaces in PHP is great. Having '\' as namespace separator is a little bit ... awkward (but if there is someone who thinks that is cool & sexy, I am adding tag "rant" to this post. ;) .

So, here goes the question:

Are you using in your code NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR constant? As in code below:

```
<?php

if (!\defined('NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR') {

    \define('NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR', '\\');

} // if
```

Pros:

- consistent with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (which **all** of us are using ;)
- no mess with escaping (think of *'\Foo\Bar'* but *'\\' . Foo' . '\\' . 'Bar'*)
- more readable (IMHO)
- which gives us in effect an opportunity to write good, namespace-aware autoloaders
- can resist another change if something scary happens (as with ol'good '::' from PHP 6 alpha)
- can hide uniquess of '\' as namespace operator in programming language land from strangers ;)

Cons:

- "The reason for `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is that the value is platform dependent, the namespace separator isn't." (as stated in http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43046)
- 19 characters instead of 1 ( *\* ) or 4 (*'\\'*)
- There are places where you can't use this (full qualified class names as default class variables) ie:

  ```
  <?php

  class A {

      protected $sDefaultReporterClass = '\My\Namespace\DefaultReporter';

  }
  ```

So, what are you thinking ?

Comment: I'm thinking you're thinking too much. If *you* want to implement a userland `NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR` constant then go right ahead; if it works for you then great, otherwise stick with typing it out normally like the rest of us. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I got your point at all... PHP constants are not like C preprocessor macros. You cannot create a macro and replace an operator with it—it just won't work:

```
<?php
define('ADD', '+');
echo (3 ADD 5); // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
?>
```

Even if it worked, what's the purpose? Hiding the syntax of a language to make it look like another language you are more familiar with is a quite a waste of time, not to mention that it makes it harder for other coders to work on the project. If you think language X looks cooler, well, just code X rather than PHP :)

### Update

Using the namespace separator in places where it's required to be a string (such autoloaders and callbacks) offers little difficulty when using single quotes since the only places where it needs to be escaped is right before a quote or another backslash, thus it can be written as-is:

```
$callback = 'Foo\Bar';
```

All other options look to me like unnecessary complexity:

```
$callback = "Foo\\Bar";
$callback = 'Foo' . NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR . 'Bar';
$callback = "Foo{$namespace_separator}Bar";
```

Comment: well, you completly missed the point. My question concerns usage of namespace separator in autoloaders and callbacks, where, generally, you use it as a part of string.

Comment: yes, if you know your "Foo" and "Bar". And that is not always given. You face often things like, say,  *$packagee .'\\' . $class*

Comment: Yeah, try using it in a regular expression. \\\\\\\\\ anyone? (yes, I intentionally exaggerated the number of backslashes)

Answer (score 6):

Yes is the answer to your question. I do use a self defined NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR because

```
str_replace(NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classFileName);
```

is clearer to me than

```
str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classFileName);
```

It may only be used in my autoloaders but I want to quickly understand the code if I happen to read it a few years down the line.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now more or less resolved by using a new (PHP >5.5) approach in addressing class names by using [class name resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) (in the PHP RFC it was called [class name scalars](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars)).

While using strings filled with class names is still useful for all kinds of magic, particularly auto-loading, using fully qualified class names as hard-coded strings are error prone and hard to detect for IDE's.

As how this answers the original question: Sometimes a namespace separator constant is useful for very specific parts of your code although I would come across less places where I would actually use it.

In your example you would rather use:

```
<?php

namespace My\Namespace;

class A {
    protected $sDefaultReporterClass = DefaultReporter::class;
// or
    protected $sAnotherReporterClass = \Other\Namespace\Reporter::class;
}
```

When the scope of this issue is so small it will only be used in a specific part of the code this will probably not legitimize a PHP build-in constant. If so, other operators like the scope operator should be included as a constant as well. The PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM constant for "::"? (Sorry for the small constant naming phun)

A unimplemented PHP feature that could come in handy following this approach would be the magic Class::namespace constant.